# When using "rintrojs" package in shiny app with modules (golem), dialog box from step-by-step introduction appears top left corner

Tags: r, shiny, module, shinyapps, golem

I'm trying to create a introduction with pop-up text boxes using "rintrojs" package.
The thing is that I am using modules with golem in my app, so there is one module per each tab.

The problem i'm getting is that when running the app and clicking the button to display the introduction, the 2 dialog boxes appear at the top left corner of the screen.
I'm having the same issue as reported here: [Using the ‘rintrojs’ in Shiny to create e step-by-step introductions on app usage; dialog box appears top left corner for some tabs but not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66906286/using-the-rintrojs-in-shiny-to-create-e-step-by-step-introductions-on-app-usag)

The difference is that I'm working with modules and the solution proposed here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70162738/14615249) doesn't work for me.

Here is the problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8UiP.png)

And here is some reproducible code so it gets easier to understand:

```r
library(shiny)
library(rintrojs)
library(shinyWidgets)

# UI Module 1
mod_module1_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    rintrojs::introjsUI(),
    column(
      width = 12,
      actionButton(
        inputId = ns("bt"),
        label = "Display Button"
      )
    ),
    div(
      sidebarPanel(
        style = "height: 100px;",
        width = 12,
        shiny::column(
          width = 3,
          rintrojs::introBox(
            shiny::numericInput(
              inputId = ns("numeric"),
              label = "Numeric Input",
              value = 45
            ),
            data.step = 1,
            data.intro = div(
              h5("Description goes here")
            )
          ),
        ),
        shiny::column(
          width = 3,
          rintrojs::introBox(
            shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
              inputId = ns("picker"),
              label = "Picker Input",
              choices = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
            ),
            data.step = 2,
            data.intro = div(
              h5("Description goes here")
            )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
}

# SERVER Module 1
mod_module1_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    observeEvent(input$bt, rintrojs::introjs(session))

  })
}


# UI Module 2
mod_module2_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    rintrojs::introjsUI(),
    column(
      width = 12,
      actionButton(
        inputId = ns("bt"),
        label = "Display Button"
      )
    ),
    div(
      sidebarPanel(
        style = "height: 100px;",
        width = 12,
        shiny::column(
          width = 3,
          rintrojs::introBox(
            shiny::numericInput(
              inputId = ns("numeric"),
              label = "Numeric Input",
              value = 45
            ),
            data.step = 1,
            data.intro = div(
              h5("Description goes here")
            )
          ),
        ),
        shiny::column(
          width = 3,
          rintrojs::introBox(
            shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
              inputId = ns("picker"),
              label = "Picker Input",
              choices = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
            ),
            data.step = 2,
            data.intro = div(
              h5("Description goes here")
            )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
}

# SERVER Module 2
mod_module2_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    observeEvent(input$bt, rintrojs::introjs(session))
  })
}
 
# APP UI 
app_ui <- function(request) {
  tagList(
    shiny::navbarPage(
      title = ("Example"),
      fluid = TRUE,

      # 1 - Tab 1 ----
      tabPanel(
        title = "tab1",
        shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(
          title = span(
            h1("Title tab 1")
          )
        ),
        shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
          mod_module1_ui("module1_1")
        ),
      ),
      # 2 - Tab 2 ----
      shiny::tabPanel(
        title = "tab2",
        shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(
          title = h1("Title tab 2")
        ),
        shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
          mod_module2_ui("module2_1")
        ),
      ),
    )
  )
}

# APP SERVER
app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mod_module1_server("module1_1")
  mod_module2_server("module2_1")
}

shinyApp(app_ui, app_server)
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Ps: This is my first ever question here in StackOverFlow, so I'd like to apologize in advance if I'm missing important parts of how to ask the question.
Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem was addressed in [this Github issue](https://github.com/carlganz/rintrojs/issues/24) but I write a summary and a similar solution here.

`rintrojs` works by adding attributes to the HTML elements you want to highlight. For example, it adds `data-step=1` as an attribute of the numeric input. The problem is that if you create multiple tours, there will be several elements with the attribute `data-step=1`, which means that `rintrojs` will not be able to know which one is the "true first step". This is why only the page top left corner is highlighted.

One solution (detailed in the issue I referred to) is to create the list of steps in the server of each module. Therefore, each time the server part of the module will be called, it will reset the steps of rintrojs, so that there is only one `data-step=1` for example.

Here's your example adapted:

```r
library(shiny)
library(rintrojs)
library(shinyWidgets)

# UI Module 1
mod_module1_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    rintrojs::introjsUI(),
    column(
      width = 12,
      actionButton(
        inputId = ns("bt"),
        label = "Display Button"
      )
    ),
    div(
      sidebarPanel(
        style = "height: 100px;",
        width = 12,
        shiny::column(
          width = 3,
          shiny::numericInput(
            inputId = ns("numeric"),
            label = "Numeric Input",
            value = 45
          )
        ),
        shiny::column(
          width = 3,
          div(
            id = ns("mypicker"),
            shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
              inputId = ns("picker"),
              label = "Picker Input",
              choices = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
            )
          )
        ),
      ),
    )
  )
}

# SERVER Module 1
mod_module1_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    intro <- reactive({
      data.frame(
       element = paste0("#", session$ns(c("numeric", "mypicker"))),
       intro = paste(c("Slider", "Button"), id)
     )
    })
    observeEvent(input$bt, rintrojs::introjs(session, options = list(steps = intro())))
    
  })
}


# UI Module 2
mod_module2_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    column(
      width = 12,
      actionButton(
        inputId = ns("bt"),
        label = "Display Button"
      )
    ),
    div(
      sidebarPanel(
        style = "height: 100px;",
        width = 12,
        shiny::column(
          width = 3,
          shiny::numericInput(
            inputId = ns("numeric"),
            label = "Numeric Input",
            value = 45
          )
        ),
        shiny::column(
          width = 3,
          div(
            id = ns("mypicker"),
            shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
              inputId = ns("picker"),
              label = "Picker Input",
              choices = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
            )
          )
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
}

# SERVER Module 2
mod_module2_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    intro <- reactive({
      data.frame(
        element = paste0("#", session$ns(c("numeric", "mypicker"))),
        intro = paste(c("Slider", "Button"), id)
      )
    })
    observeEvent(input$bt, rintrojs::introjs(session, options = list(steps = intro())))
  })
}

# APP UI 
app_ui <- function(request) {
  tagList(
    shiny::navbarPage(
      title = ("Example"),
      fluid = TRUE,
      
      # 1 - Tab 1 ----
      tabPanel(
        title = "tab1",
        shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(
          title = span(
            h1("Title tab 1")
          )
        ),
        shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
          mod_module1_ui("module1_1")
        ),
      ),
      # 2 - Tab 2 ----
      shiny::tabPanel(
        title = "tab2",
        shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(
          title = h1("Title tab 2")
        ),
        shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
          mod_module2_ui("module2_1")
        ),
      ),
    )
  )
}

# APP SERVER
app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mod_module1_server("module1_1")
  mod_module2_server("module2_1")
}

shinyApp(app_ui, app_server)
```

Note that using `"picker"` in the dataframe containing the steps doesn't really work (only a very small part of the pickerInput is highlighted). This is why I wrap the pickers in `div()` and use the id of this `div()` instead.